# iphone : How to set Font size in webView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am creating HTML using following code :

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"<html> \n" "<head> \n"
                        "<style type=\"/css\"> \n"
                        "body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@;}\n"
                        "</style> \n"
                        "</head> \n"
                        "<body>%@</body> \n"
                        "</html>",@"Helvetica",[NSNumber numberWithInt:17],
                        @"<p><i>My data</p>"];
```

Here I am giving `[NSNumber numberWithInt:17]` for font size but any change in this `17` dosen't making changes in font size of HTML.

What should I do ?

Comment: Is that really how you are using stringWithFormat? If so, you should check the string that it produces using NSLog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem was that you had the wrong style type – `/css` and not `text/css`.

```
"<style type=\"text/css\"> \n"
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a unit attached to it. the CSS font-size property needs to be

```
font-size: 17px
```

or you could also use em or percentages

Answer (score 2):

Passing `[NSNumber numberWithInt:17];` doesn't passes the actual value, it just passes the object reference. So, you should be passing it like this,

```
font-size: %dpx;
```

And the value as just,

```
17
```